# Get values from first sorted member of grouped(?) sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I feel like this is obvious but i'm struggling.  Must be because it's a monday.

I have a `licenses` table in MySQL which has fields `id (int)`, `start_date (date)`, `licensable_id (int)`, `licensable_type (string)` and `fixed_end_point (boolean)`.

I want to get all licenses where the start date is equal to or less than today, group them by `licensable_id and licensable_type`, and then get the most **recently starting one** so I can get the `fixed_end_point` field out of it, along with `licensable_id` and `licensable_type`.

This is what i'm trying:

```
SELECT licensable_id, licensable_type, fixed_end_point
FROM licenses
WHERE start_date <= "2016-08-01"
GROUP BY licensable_id, licensable_type
ORDER BY start_date desc;
```

At the moment, the `ORDER BY` field seems to be being ignored, and it's just returning the values from the first license for each group, rather than the most recent.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to make a nested query?

Comment: Invalid ORDER BY. When GROUP BY (and SELECT DISTINCT and UNION etc) only select list items may be specified in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be thinking about this as a `group by`.  You want to select the most recent `start_date` for each license, given the constraints in the question.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*
from licenses l
where l.start_date = (select max(l2.start_date)
                      from licenses l2
                      where l2.licensable_id = l.licensable_id and
                            l2.licensable_type = l.licensable_type and
                            l2.start_date <= '2016-08-01'
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!  You have a typo in your answer: `l2.licensable_type = l2.licensable_type and` should be `l2.licensable_type = l.licensable_type and`

Answer (score 2):

You don't use aggregation function so you should use distinct

```
SELECT  DISTINCT licensable_id, licensable_type, fixed_end_point
FROM licenses
WHERE date(start_date)  <= date(now())
ORDER BY start_date desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Does MySQL execute that query? (According to ANSI SQL you can only ORDER BY selected columns when SELECT DISTINCT.)

Comment: the resulting are ordered.. i Know ANSI standard ( and I alway select the column for order by  but th OP no in this case)  but this is a mysql possible  behavior

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't give you the results you want is how GROUP CONCAT works.

With standard SQL any field in the SELECT must either be also mentioned in the GROUP BY clause or must be an aggregate field (there is an exception for fields 100% related to a field that is returned, but many flavours of SQL do not support this).

MySQL does allow a field to be in the SELECT clause which is not an aggregate value and is not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause, and allowing this was the default until recently. However for these fields there could be multiple values for the GROUP BY fields, and in this case which one is chosen is not defined. As this is worked out prior to the ORDER BY statement being processed, the ORDER BY clause has no effect on which one is chosen.

There are a few normal ways to do this. You can use a  as Gordon has suggested, or similarly (and possibly more efficiently depending on records and indexes) you can use a sub query to get the latest rows date for each of your important rows, and then join that back to your main table:-

```
SELECT l.licensable_id, 
        l.licensable_type, 
        l.fixed_end_point
FROM licenses l
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT licensable_id, 
            licensable_type, 
            MAX(l2.start_date) AS max_start_date
    FROM licenses 
    GROUP BY licensable_id, 
            licensable_type
) sub0
ON l.licensable_id = sub0.licensable_id
AND l.licensable_type = sub0.licensable_type
AND l.start_date = sub0.max_start_date
```

In some situations another option is to (ab)use the GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions. This way you can GROUP BY the fields you want to, but do a GROUP_CONCAT or the other fields in the descending order of the date. Then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get everything up to the first comma (the default delimiter for GROUP_CONCAT):-

```
SELECT licensable_id, 
        licensable_type, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(fixed_end_point, '') ORDER BY start_date DESC), ',', 1)
FROM licenses
WHERE start_date <= "2016-08-01"
GROUP BY licensable_id, licensable_type
```

Obviously this has issues if the latest row has a null value, hence I have used COALESCE to fudge in non null values. Also if the field contains commas you will need to use an alternative delimiter. And if the field is large then you might have issues with the max field length for GROUP_CONCAT (default is 1024 I think).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!